# Do all EM waves (of different wavelengths) travel at the same speed for a given medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

All electromagnetic waves travel at the same speed when traveling through a vacuum.

But, for example, do light, FM radio, and X-rays travel through air at the same speed?  Through water?

Comment: [The wikipedia article describing the dispersion relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) may be helpful.